# How to get carousel slider data in firebase firestore with flutter package carousel_slider

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What I would like is to retrieve the data from a Firebase Firestore query instead of the List I created manually. Here I am using a flutter package which is CarouselSlider and I am retrieving the data from a list written manually by myself while what I would like is to retrieve the content of my slider from a query. Thanks for your help.

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flyzik/size_config.dart';

class SliderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const SliderWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> fetchList() async {
    const path = 'slide';
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path).doc().get();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: fetchList(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print("****************MY SLIDE CONTENT: " +
            snapshot.data!.toString());
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: Text('Loading...'));
        }
        final imgList = List<String>.from(snapshot.data! as List);
        return Container(
          child: CarouselSlider(
            options: CarouselOptions(
              autoPlay: true,
              aspectRatio: 2.0,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.height,
            ),
            items: imageSlider(imgList),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  List<Widget> imageSlider(List<String> imgList) => imgList
      .map(
        (item) => Container(
          child: Container(
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
              child: Center(
                child: Image.network(
                  item,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  width: 1500.0,
                  height: getProportionateScreenHeight(300),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
      .toList();
}
```

This my DB structure[MY DATABASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObzU8.png)

I have these errors:
[Error in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oSqp.png)
[Eror on emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkwGu.png)

Comment: Are you asking how to [read from Firestore in Flutter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That doesn't really answer my question

Comment: There is no question in your post, which is why I showed you how to get started reading the data from Firestore. If that is not what you are asking, please edit your question to clarify what you're asking of us.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen What I want is to display a carousel slider with content from my firestore database via a query

Comment: Can you include the code you've attempted? That's how SO works - you attempt some code and when you get stuck, post it and your troubleshooting and we'll take a look. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Jay My code it is well there present what are in image are the data base and the error display

Comment: Please re-read the link. **You should not post code (or error/exception messages, log files, configuration files, project files, or anything else that is represented in textual form) as an image because** The key to your issue is in the error message but because it's a link to an image, future readers will not be able to locate that error message because it was not included in the question.